# Why does my UnicodeFont (Slick2D) not draw?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

So I am trying to draw a font using Slick2D's UnicodeFont. The code that loads the font:

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
UnicodeFont uFont = new UnicodeFont(font);
uFont.addAsciiGlyphs(); 
uFont.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect(java.awt.Color.BLACK));
uFont.loadGlyphs();
```

It's more or less copied and pasted from the wiki. Next, during a frame I use gluOrtho2d() and reset the projection and modelview matrices. Then I call

```
this.font.drawString(100, 50, "some text goes here");
```

to actually draw the text. But all I get is an empty screen, an no errors of any kind.

Comment: Ok. So apparently there was an issue with an openGL setting (face culling), but now it is displayed upside down instead.

Comment: As they say; when you start explaining the problem to someone else, you often instantly see the solution. And long live openGL transformations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that UnicodeFonts are depreciated in the current version of slick 2d, I recomend you folow my steps for using AngelCodeFonts on this related question: [Slick2D Fonts don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157346/slick2d-fonts-dont-work)

Comment: Wait what, they are deprecated?

Comment: yea in the API docs it says in the description, as well as in the wiki (I think...)

Comment: I guess its just true type font. Angel code fonts work as well and a tutorial for that is in the linked questions